# Menu burger animation triggered by clicking anywhere on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I followed a tutorial on how to create an animated menu burger, but there are a few bugs. The animation works the way I want it to so far, but it's triggered regardless of where I click on the page. I've provided the code here:

```js
    const toggleMenu = document.querySelector(
        '.menu-btn');
    let isOpen = false;
    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (!isOpen) {
            toggleMenu.classList.add('open');
            isOpen = true;
        } else {
            toggleMenu.classList.remove('open');
            isOpen = false;
        }
    });
```

```css
.grid-container {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-areas: "header menu";
     grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    }

    .header {
     grid-area: header;
     grid-column: span 7;
     margin: 2px;
     background-color: black;
    }

    .menu {
     grid-area: menu;
     grid-column: span 1;
     display: flex;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
    }
    .menu-btn {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     width: 80%;
     height: 80%;
     transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     //border: 2px solid #fff;
    }

    .btn-mid {
     position: relative;
     width: 25px;
     height: 3px;
     background: #fff;
     border-radius: 2px;
     transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .btn-mid::before,
    .btn-mid::after {
     position: absolute; /*Necessary for 3 bars*/
     content:'';
     width: 25px;
     height: 3px;
     background: #fff;
     border-radius: 2px;
     transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    }
    .btn-mid::before {
     transform: translateY(-300%);
    }

    .btn-mid::after {
     transform: translateY(300%);
    }

    .top-menu {
     transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 100%; /*So that we can't initially see*/
     width: 100%;
     height: 50vh;
     z-index: -1;
     background: #000;
    }

    .top-menu-box {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
    }

    .top-menu-box ul {
     list-style: none;
     text-align: center;
    }

    .top-menu-box ul li:hover {
     border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
     transition: 0.25s;
    }

    .top-menu-box ul li a {
     color: #fff;
    }

    /*BUTTON ANIMATION*/
    .menu-btn.open .btn-mid {
     transform: translateX(-175%);
     background: transparent;
    }

    .menu-btn.open .btn-mid::before {
     transform: rotate(45deg) translate(125%, -1050%);
    }

    .menu-btn.open .btn-mid::after {
     transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(125%, 1050%);
    }

    .menu-btn.open .top-menu {
     bottom: 50%;
    }

    .menu-btn.open .top-menu-box {
     width: 100%;
    }
    /*END*/

    .nav-test {
      display: flex;
      direction: row;
      overflow: hidden;
      justify-content: space-around;
      padding: 0; //By default, padding is set
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    .nav-test a {
     color: white;
    }

    .menu {
     display: flex;
     grid-area: menu;
     grid-column: span 1;
     margin: 2px;
     background-color: black;
    }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu_design.css">
 
    <head>
     <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="item header">
       <ul class="nav-test">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="item menu">
       <div class="menu-btn">
        <div id="middle" class="btn-mid"></div>
       </div>
       <script src="response.js"></script>
      </div>
      <div class="top-menu">
       <div class="top-menu-box">
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </head>
   </html>
```

I used percentages for the attribute values because I want it to adjust according to the size of the screen.

I also noticed that when I view it from my desktop, the animation seems kind of choppy. Does anyone have any advice on what to do?

By the way, I know there's an extra bullet list, and this is for a sliding menu that opens when the burger is pressed, but that's unrelated.

Comment: Instead of `document.addEventListener` use `toggleMenu.addEventListener`

Answer (score 1):

You use `document.addEventListener`, change this with `toggleMenu.addEventListener`

```js
    const toggleMenu = document.querySelector(
        '.menu-btn');
    let isOpen = false;
    toggleMenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (!isOpen) {
            toggleMenu.classList.add('open');
            isOpen = true;
        } else {
            toggleMenu.classList.remove('open');
            isOpen = false;
        }
    });
```

```css
.grid-container {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-areas: "header menu";
     grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    }

    .header {
     grid-area: header;
     grid-column: span 7;
     margin: 2px;
     background-color: black;
    }

    .menu {
     grid-area: menu;
     grid-column: span 1;
     display: flex;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
    }
    .menu-btn {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     width: 80%;
     height: 80%;
     transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     //border: 2px solid #fff;
    }

    .btn-mid {
     position: relative;
     width: 25px;
     height: 3px;
     background: #fff;
     border-radius: 2px;
     transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .btn-mid::before,
    .btn-mid::after {
     position: absolute; /*Necessary for 3 bars*/
     content:'';
     width: 25px;
     height: 3px;
     background: #fff;
     border-radius: 2px;
     transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    }
    .btn-mid::before {
     transform: translateY(-300%);
    }

    .btn-mid::after {
     transform: translateY(300%);
    }

    .top-menu {
     transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 100%; /*So that we can't initially see*/
     width: 100%;
     height: 50vh;
     z-index: -1;
     background: #000;
    }

    .top-menu-box {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
    }

    .top-menu-box ul {
     list-style: none;
     text-align: center;
    }

    .top-menu-box ul li:hover {
     border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
     transition: 0.25s;
    }

    .top-menu-box ul li a {
     color: #fff;
    }

    /*BUTTON ANIMATION*/
    .menu-btn.open .btn-mid {
     transform: translateX(-175%);
     background: transparent;
    }

    .menu-btn.open .btn-mid::before {
     transform: rotate(45deg) translate(125%, -1050%);
    }

    .menu-btn.open .btn-mid::after {
     transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(125%, 1050%);
    }

    .menu-btn.open .top-menu {
     bottom: 50%;
    }

    .menu-btn.open .top-menu-box {
     width: 100%;
    }
    /*END*/

    .nav-test {
      display: flex;
      direction: row;
      overflow: hidden;
      justify-content: space-around;
      padding: 0; //By default, padding is set
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    .nav-test a {
     color: white;
    }

    .menu {
     display: flex;
     grid-area: menu;
     grid-column: span 1;
     margin: 2px;
     background-color: black;
    }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu_design.css">
 
    <head>
     <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="item header">
       <ul class="nav-test">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="item menu">
       <div class="menu-btn">
        <div id="middle" class="btn-mid"></div>
       </div>
       <script src="response.js"></script>
      </div>
      <div class="top-menu">
       <div class="top-menu-box">
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </head>
   </html>
```